# MySql between dates

Tags: mysql

I am using LEFT JOIN, with between dates but its not working

```
$start = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST["demo1"]));

$end = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST["demo2"]));

$query = "SELECT Coloums FROM bilty 
          LEFT JOIN runningexp ON bilty.bilty_no=runningexp.bilty_no 
          WHERE bilty.vehicle = '$vehicle' 
          AND bilty.date1 BETWEEN '$start' and '$end' Order by bilty.bilty_no";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the datatype of `date1`

Comment: what problem is it giving you ? any error or incorrect output ?

Comment: "its not working" is not helping. Is there an error message? What is the output? What did you expect?

Comment: What do you see when you print/log the SQL statement in `$query`?

Comment: @diEcho; date1 have type date

Comment: @PiTheNumber: it is not showing records when i run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Coloums 
FROM bilty LEFT JOIN runningexp ON bilty.bilty_no=runningexp.bilty_no 
WHERE bilty.vehicle = '$vehicle' 
         AND 
      DATE(bilty.date1) BETWEEN date('$start') and DATE('$end')
Order by bilty.bilty_no
```